# Documentation-generator for Ant?

Tags: ant, documentation, documentation-generation

At my company we have a very complex build-system based on Ant. Understanding it took me a long time. I'm currently restructuring it and would also make it easier for new developers to win through it.

Is there any (good) documentation-generator that can generate a documentation based on build.xml-files and their includes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write XSLT rules to convert it to HTML with the links or smth like this.

(Hmm, or much easier may be using CSS for build.xml)

i.e.

```
<target name="tar1" depends="tar2, tar3">
....
</target>
```

will come to

```
<div class="target">
    <a name="tar1"><p class="name">tar1</p></a>
    <div class="deps-list">
        Depends on:
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tar2">tar2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tar3">tar3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        Tasks:
        <ul>
            <li><p class="taskname">Copy</p><p class="taskargs">args...</p></li>
            ...
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```